# Visual Studio Solution -- Any way to create a "special" folder?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, project, special-folders, solution-explorer

Basically, I want one of my folders to appear above the other folders as a type of "special folder", similar to how Properties has it's own special place even though it's a folder, same with App_Data, etc.

Is this possible?

Comment: I usually create a solution folder.

Comment: You want this at the solution level or the project level?

Comment: Solution folders are sorted alphabetically.

Comment: If being the first "non-special" folder is acceptable, you can always start the name with an underscore. As James pointed out, the folders are sorted alphabetically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, Visual Studio doesn't support adding special project folders.  The Properties folder is hard-coded to behave the way that it does.

However, anything is possible with code. You could build an extension to do this, but it wouldn't be simple.  You'd probably need to mess around with the `IVsHierarchy` or even implement a [project subtype](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166488.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

> Basically, I want one of my folders to
>   appear above the other folders as a
>   type of "special folder", similar to
>   how Properties has it's own special
>   place even though it's a folder, same
>   with App_Data, etc.
>
> Is this possible?

Yes:

1. Do it manually through the IDE
2. Write your own script to
   generate/modify your `*.sln`/`*.vcproj`

For (1) "manual" on solutions in the IDE:  `Solution Explorer`, `right-click` on `Solution node`==>`Add`==>`New Solution Folder`.

While typically the folders are sorted alphabetically (I'd insert a leading underscore to force your special folder to the top), solution folders inserted manually on my MSVS2008 leave the new folder "at the top", even though it should have bumped down when alphabetically sorted.  However, folders under a `Project` (which are called "`Filters`") are always sorted alphabetically, and added similarly from the right-click, and then you can modify their "filter properties" with file name globs for what you want in there (e.g., add a filter glob for "`*.MY_EXTENSION1;*.MY_EXTENSION2`").

We chose (2), and we generate our own `*.sln` and `*.vcproj`, adding our own folders/filters.  I've not seen any utilities on the web to help with that (so we had to write our own).  The formats are not too hard to reverse engineer, but it's largely undocumented XML, so you have to experiment.  There are only a couple good web articles explaining what's in the file, like this one:

http://tim.oreilly.com/pub/a/dotnet/excerpt/vshacks_chap1/index.html?page=4

On the "bright side", the files are only XML, so in developing our scripts we merely made changes through the IDE, saved, and compared the "diffs" for what change we want.  Those changes are what our scripts insert when we modify our files.  So, if you modify the file manually, you can similarly just "`diff`" the file to see what changed, and make your own script.  (IMHO, this is the fastest and easiest route, since tools generally do not exist to manipulate these files.)

Tools like `CMake` and `QMake` generate `*.vcproj`/`*.sln`, but don't really do the folder customization thing like you're talking.  However, we look at their output too, because, "there's more than one way to do things" in these files, and the files seem to have many undocumented features for doing different clever things that somehow these tools have "discovered" (so you can try to copy their generated output).

We found the .NET APIs to work with these files as too much work, and not really designed for that type of manipulation, but YMMV.

Comment: >>largely undocumented XML, so you have to experiment<< The project and solution files for Visual Studio 2005+ are MSBuild files. There is nothing to hack.

Comment: >>the files seem to have many undocumented features for doing different clever things that somehow these tools have "discovered"<< These undocumented features are features of MSBuild.

Comment: This will not work on VS2010.  VS2008 has a bug that causes the projects to be in the order they are in the project file.  I wrote a small tool for myself and my team mates a while back to alphabetically sort projects in the .sln file to fix this.  VS2010 fixes this behavior so if you're going for names you'll have to use some underscore trick or the likes of it.

Comment: @sprite -- good to know, thanks (I thought the VS2008 behavior was strange to not sort)

Comment: There's another issue- he asks about adding special folders to a *project* (e.g. the "Properties" folder in the project).  You're talking about adding special *solution* folders.

Comment: @Matt - Yeah I got his question but AFAIK there is not way to do this unless he want to write a VS2010 extension, and writing one isn't a walk in the park from what I understand.  What I suggested is a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

VS 2012 has a feature that I just found, and it solved this problem for me. It may not be new to VS.

Create a folder under the project with a leading "_" (to get it sorted first).

On the folder's properties set "Namespace Provider" to false.

VS (or ReSharper?) code analysis then does not complain that "the namespace does not match file location", which was the source of irritation for me that would otherwise have kept me from going this route.

Answer (score 1):

Although there is no easy way to add `Custom Folder`, there is an easy way to "steal" `Properties` custom folder.

1. Add a regular folder to the project. For example `MyCustomerFolder`.
2. Open proj file xml. Find line

   ```
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
   ```

   replace with

   ```
    <AppDesignerFolder>MyCustomFolder</AppDesignerFolder>
   ```
3. Reload the project.
4. Now you've got a custom folder, that will always stick to the top.

   [image]

Comment: This is a nice trick, but this doesn't work if you want to add more than 1 special folder.

Comment: @Matt - true. However, the question clearly states "I want one of my folders to appear above the other folders".

Comment: Yup, you're right.  Though it would also be a problem if he actually needs to use the App Designer folder and wants to keep it independent of his "special folder".

Comment: Nice trick, but yea... this doesn't solve the issue of generating an additional special folder.