# Custom reference types

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-addins, visual-studio-sdk

It's always been possible to add references for your project in Visual Studio. These show up under the special "References" folder in the solution explorer. You can also add service references, which also get put under their own special folder. I'd like to create my own reference type, complete with special folder, that other projects can use. What is this called, and where is some good documentation on how to do this?

Comment: Do you want to create a library? (you said :I'd like to create my own reference type..) or VS plugins?

Comment: What would be the purpose of such a thing?

Comment: Similar to the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202895/visual-studio-solution-any-way-to-create-a-special-folder. It contains some useful feedback.

Comment: @adatapost it would be a VS plugin which enables a new type of reference.

Answer (score 1):

You mean you want to create a library of classes / a .dll?

http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/3861

Comment: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)